# Finding a tight lower bound for $\left(\frac{1+x}{(1+x/2)^2}\right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics, exponentiation

I am trying to find a tight lower bound for $\left(\frac{1+x}{(1+x/2)^2}\right)^n$ as a function of $x$ and $n$ and for large $n$, 
where $x$ changes with $n$  such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x=0$.

I am not sure wether my approach to solve this is right or not, but this is what I did:
\begin{align*}\left(\frac{1+x}{(1+x/2)^2}\right)^n&=e^{n(\ln({1+x})-2\ln{(1+x/2)})}\\
&=e^{n(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots-2(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{x^3}{24}-\cdots))}\\
&=e^{n(-\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^3}{4}-\frac{15x^4}{64}+\cdots)}\\
&\geq  e^{n(-\frac{x^2}{4})}\\
&=1-(n\frac{x^2}{4})+(n\frac{x^2}{4})^2-\cdots \\ 
&\geq 1-(n\frac{x^2}{4}) 
\end{align*}
We know $\lim_{n\to\infty}x=0$, but we don't know whether $\lim_{n\to\infty}nx^2=0$ . Hence, the last inequality is not necessarily correct, 
because the sum of the terms after $1-(n\frac{x^2}{4}) $ may not be greater than zero.

Comment: how is $x$ a function of $n$???

Comment: The exact relationship between $x$ and $n$  is not specified. We only know  $\lim_{n\to\infty}x=0$.

Comment: For $n$ large enough you could use Bernoulli's inequality to bound $(1 + x)^n$ from below by $1 + nx$. From there I'm not sure how to proceed without more information about $x(n)$. (This probably isn't a "tight" bound anyway.)

Comment: @rwbogl and how should I bound the term in the denominator?

Comment: I seem to get $e^{-nx^2/4}$ (I think your $16$ should be an $8$) but the difference hardly matters: you clearly get different limits with $x=n^{-1}$, $x=n^{-1/2}$ and $x=n^{-1/4}$

Comment: @Mah To bound the denominator using my idea, I think you'll need to know more about the exact behavior of x as a function of n.

Comment: @Henry You are right, 16 should be an 8. I edited the question.

Comment: @rwbogl Let $x=cn^{-1/2}$, so $nx^2$ is a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $y = x/2$.
Then
$\left(\frac{1+x}{(1+x/2)^2}\right)^n
=\left(\frac{1+2y}{(1+y)^2}\right)^n
=\frac{(1+2y)^n}{(1+y)^{2n}}
$.

Since
$(1+2y)^n
=\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}2^jy^j
$
and
$\frac1{(1+y)^{2n}}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n+k-1}{k}(-1)^ky^k
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{(1+2y)^n}{(1+y)^{2n}}
&=\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}2^jy^j\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n+k-1}{k}(-1)^ky^k\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}y^{j+k} \binom{n}{j}2^j \binom{2n+k-1}{k}(-1)^k\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}y^m\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}2^j \binom{2n+m-j-1}{m-j}(-1)^{m-j}\qquad j+k = m, k = m-j\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}y^m(-1)^m\sum_{j=0}^n\dfrac{n!(2n+m-j-1)!}{j!(n-j)!(m-j)!(2n-1)!}2^j (-1)^{j}\\
&=\dfrac{n!}{(2n-1)!}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}y^m(-1)^m\sum_{j=0}^n\dfrac{(2n+m-j-1)!}{j!(n-j)!(m-j)!}2^j (-1)^{j}\\
\text{so}\\
\frac{(1+x)^n}{(1+x/2)^{2n}}
&=\dfrac{n!}{(2n-1)!}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-1)^m2^{-m}x^m\sum_{j=0}^{\min(m, n)}\dfrac{(2n+m-j-1)!}{j!(n-j)!(m-j)!}2^j (-1)^{j}\\
\end{array}
$

With this,
you can get the power series.

Note:
Wolfy says this starts like

$1-\dfrac{nx^2}{4}+\dfrac{nx^3}{4}+\dfrac{n(n-7)x^4}{32}
 -\dfrac{n(n - 3)  x^5}{16} - \dfrac{n (n^2 - 33 n + 62) x^6}{384}+O(x^7)
$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is exactly what I was looking for. I just don't understand how $n$ turned into $\min(m,n)$ (in the upper limit of the inner summation)?

Comment: Because of the $(n-j)!(m-j)!$ in the denominator.

Comment: I see. So that is because $j+k=m$ and thus $j\leq m$.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I think in the outer sum there should be a  $2^{-m}$, not $2^{m}$.

Comment: Is there a shortcut to find out how the terms in $O(x^5)$ depend on $n$?

Comment: @Mah: Thanks - corrected.

Comment: @Mah: The next two terms according to Wolfy have been added.

Comment: Thank you for adding the next two terms. Based on your last equation I guess the coefficient of $x^m$ scales like $n^{\lfloor{m/2} \rfloor }$ (I asked it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2750304/edit). But I have no idea how to prove it. Do you think my guess is correct? Could you also help with that question? @marty

Answer (score 0):

Start considering $$y=\frac{1+x}{1+\left(\frac x2 \right)^2}$$ and use Taylor around $x=0$; this will give
$$y=1+x-\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^3}{4}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ Now, use the binomial expansion and get
$$y^n=1+nx+\frac n4 (2n-3)x^2+\frac n{12}(2 n^2-9 n+4)x^3+O\left(x^4\right)$$ Define $t=nx$ and you can write as
$$y^n=1+t+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{4 n}\right) t^2+\left(\frac{1}{6}-\frac{3}{4 n}+\frac{1}{3 n^2}\right)t^3+O\left(t^5\right)\tag 1$$ So, for large $n$
$$y^n <1+t+\frac 12 t^2+\frac 16 t^3\tag 2$$

Comment: I think the question says $\left(1+\frac x2 \right)^2$ rather than $1+\left(\frac x2 \right)^2$